# "Error: Invalid argument." on IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm getting the error listed below from Angular 1.5.7 on IE11.  Angular IS NOT throwing any errors on Chrome.  I tried the following:

- I've seen posts suggesting this is related to the interpolated values such as "{{model.label}}", so I added an ng-if to that, but it did not help.
- Upgraded to the latest Angular: 1.5.7.
- Upgraded jquery since I see that listed in the error stack.

  ```
   Error: Invalid argument.
     at interpolateFnWatchAction (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:9621:17)
     at interpolateFnWatcher (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:12295:17)
     at watchGroupAction (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:16952:13)
     at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:17286:23)
     at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:17552:13)
     at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:17850:11)
     at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:5955:7)
     at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6234:7) undefined
  ```

Comment: In wich directive are you using `"{{model.label}}"`?

Comment: See my answer below.  It was from the Angular Block UI directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this error was being caused by the Angular Block UI directive: https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui .  I removed that directive & the error stopped.

Comment: If you downvote, you should at least put a comment explaining what is wrong. This downvoter should get downvoted too.

Answer (score 9):

This is an **Angular known issue** as you can see in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025).

As suggested, when using directives such as `ng-placeholder` or `ng-style` you can workaround with `ng-attr-placeholder` or `ng-attr-style`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it was because I was setting the content of an element in two different ways:

```
<span ng-bind-html="functionThatGeneratesHtml()">{{ functionThatGeneratesHtml() }}</span>
```