# Angular 8 Custom Elements not working in IE11 when invoked from angular JS

Tags: angular, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, angular-elements

We are seeing the below error in the console when we launch the angular js application in IE11 browser which tries to invoke the angular 8 elements from it. It works perfectly in chrome and other browsers. Also, when we try to invoke the Angular elements from the standalone HTML page, it works fine in IE11. But, not working when invoked from the Angular JS application.

AngularJS version : 1.2.28
Angular Elements : 8

polyfills used in Angular JS application:

```
import 'console-polyfill';
import 'dom-shims/shim/HTMLDocument';
import 'es5-shim/es5-shim';
import 'es5-shim/es5-sham';
import 'html5shiv';
import 'respond.js/dest/respond.min';
import 'ewf-ie8-custom-polyfills';
import 'Base64';

angular.js application is built with webpack and translated from ES6 with es3ifyPlugin

polyfills used in Angular 8 application (custom elements):
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'classlist.js';


Polyfills tried so far with no success in the angularJS application to rectify this error,
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es7-shim/6.0.0/es7-shim.min.js
https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/custom-elements@1.5.0/custom-elements.min.js
```

[image: Error we are seeing in the console]

[image: This is the error and that corresponds to this line]

Can someone please help/guide us to resolve this error please?

Comment: I find [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946579/error-invalid-argument-on-ie11) and a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025). It seems that the error messages are the same. You can refer to the solutions to see if they can fix the issue. If it still doesn't work, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue, so that we can have a test and see how to help.